# Could CHECKSIGADD be used on new ECDSA multisignatures instead of CHECKMULTISIG?

Tags: script, multi-signature, taproot, opcodes

The proposed Taproot soft fork ([BIP 342](https://youtu.be/nXGe9_M5pjk?t=121)) defines the new opcode OP_CHECKSIGADD to verify Schnorr multisignatures whilst OP_CHECKMULTISIG (and OP_CHECKMULTISIGVERIFY) are disabled for Taproot spends (SegWit version 1). Could we use the OP_CHECKSIGADD opcode for verifying new SegWit version 0 ECDSA multisignatures? Obviously you don't get the same batch verification benefits if the individual signatures are ECDSA but it would still be more efficient to use the counter system of CHECKSIGADD?

For an explanation of how the opcode CHECKSIGADD works see this [presentation](https://youtu.be/nXGe9_M5pjk?t=121) from James Chiang. Or see Tapscript [BIP 342](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0342.mediawiki#cite_note-4).

"The opcode 186 (0xba) is named as OP_CHECKSIGADD"

"OP_CHECKSIGADD is functionally equivalent to OP_ROT OP_SWAP OP_CHECKSIG OP_ADD"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No because the opcode 186 (0xba) is undefined for SegWit version 0 spends. You can only take advantage of this opcode in SegWit version 1 spends. If you included this opcode in your SegWit version 0 transaction script any attempt to spend it would encounter this script [error](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/script/script_error.cpp#L40).

In addition Pieter Wuille added in the comments:

> In fact, enabling the same semantics for existing script versions would be a hardfork. It pops elements off the stack, so a script consisting of just "OP_CHECKSIGADD OP_SIZE 1 OP_EQUAL", and fed 3 elements as input would be invalid currently, but valid if such an opcode was added

Comment: Indeed, the opcode only exists in tapscript spends.

Comment: In fact, enabling the same semantics for existing script versions would be a hardfork. It pops elements off the stack, so a script consisting of just "OP_CHECKSIGADD OP_SIZE 1 OP_EQUAL", and fed 3 elements as input would be invalid currently, but valid if such an opcode was added.